# Ref returns undefined during shallow render Jest/Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test input onchange event in component. I have such jsx:

```
    export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    autoBind(this);
  }

  handleChangeFields() {
    const email = this.email.value;
    const password = this.password.value;

    const validationResults = {
      email: isValidEmail(email),
      password: password.length >= 8,
    };

    const isValidFields = Object.values(validationResults).every(Boolean);


  }


  render() {
    
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.validateLoginForm}>
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          ref={(input) => this.email = input}
          placeholder="Email *"
          onChange={this.handleChangeFields}
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          ref={(input) => this.password = input}
          placeholder="Password *"
          onChange={this.handleChangeFields}
        />
       
        <input
         
          type="submit"
          value="login"
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I wrote such a test to test if `handleChangeFields` was called:

```
test('should call fields change method', () => {
      const instance = wrapper.instance();
      const spyChange = jest.spyOn(instance, 'handleChangeFields');

      const input = wrapper.find('input').at(0);

      input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test@test.com' } });
      expect(spyChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

but I have an error during test call:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

but I cannot figure our why error fired. I set input's value in jest test `input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test@test.com' } });` but error still present

Comment: `handleChangeFields` is used as a callback but is not an arrow. Is it bound? I'm not sure the problem is because of refs, could be because it receives wrong `this`.

Comment: handleChangeFields isn't callback function, It is bound to the class

Comment: added whole component

Comment: It's used as a callback here, `onChange={this.handleChangeFields}`. Any way, this seems to be not the problem. Refs are a known issue, https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/1394 . Use `mount` to make Enzyme behave more like real renderer.

Comment: changed but having other issue right now. For some reason method isn't called, here is output of the test 
Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
I'll create other thread